~90's Movie (Cartoon): Evil Turns Character to Stone/Grass
Let's give this a shot.

It was a movie likely released mid-to-late 90's, definitely no
earlier than late 80's.
It is almost guaranteed a children's movie
(cartoon).
The rating was likely PG at minimum with PG-13 maximum.
It should be relatively well-known as it isn't an obscure title or from an obscure company.
This was watched in the US and was in English.
This was on VHS (no surprise for a 90's kid ^^).

My best memory is of a scene relatively close to the end where (stone / grass) is spreading (like a curse) over a characters body. This was a main character and is later cured of this evil.
I believe a witch of some sort may have been what caused the transformation as I don't recall the world being spread and turned to (stone / grass), but just that character.
Something in my mind wants to believe another main character was there to see them changed, but couldn't stop it. This didn't spread to the observer mentioned, but I believe they were in touching proximity when the transformation occurred.
What sparked my mind into thinking about this was the effect of the 'Entangling Roots' spell in Blizzard's Heroes of the Storm.
If I think of more details, I'll append accordingly.

Troll hero Stanley is turned to stone near the end of A Troll in Central Park from 1994, if that helps.

@Walt, that looks to be exactly it just based off of the cover alone. If you'd like to post that as an answer, you're a mind-saver. I tried pinging friends and they never heard of it before...

No problem, will post. It was just a shot in the dark.

@Walt I like knowing I wasn't far off in details. 'Green thumb' comes to mind now with the title. It is even more mind-bending knowing how it was deemed that terrible of a movie. RIP childhood xD.

Possibly A Troll in Central Park from 1994. From IMDb:

A friendly troll with a magic green thumb grows one flower too many for the queen, whose laws require all trolls to act meanly, be ugly and scare humans whenever possible. As a punishment, he is exiled to a world of concrete, where he should live a life of proper trolldom: Manhattan. But of all places, his pod lands in Central Park, where he feels right at home. He befriends a young brother and sister, out for the day unknown to their parents, and must immediately protect them from the queen's attack.

The queen turns the troll to stone through his friend Gus near the end, but the troll is revived later on. Here's the trailer:



